# Why MFCC have varying length dimensions?

Tags: signal-analysis, mfcc

I have recently started to use MFCC as a feature for a project. However, I am unable to understand why MFCC have varying 2nd dimension size even when I chose the number of coefficients to be 40.

Comment: It is a little bit difficult to answer this question without knowing a little bit more about the problem or how you are going about solving it (?). Which one is this varying 2nd dimension? The number of coefficients or the time dimension?

Comment: Are you simply talking about having 40 MFCC's per frame, where number of frames is dependent on the signal length?

Comment: @jojek yes, can I fix the number of frames ?

Comment: You can’t unless you trim files to the same length. Anyway if you are asking about keeping the same dimension in time then for 99% you are doing something wrong. Also have a look [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/38877/8202).